# Using Horvitz-Thompson for estimation from a simple random sample with unknown membership probability

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, point-estimation

I learnt about the Horvitz-Thompson estimator yesterday, and am trying to apply it to the degenerate case where $p$ is uniform for each, but I seem to have run into a bit of a confusing situation.

Assume I have $N$ data points $i_1, i_2 \cdots i_N$ each with an associated real-valued score $s_1, s_2, \cdots s_N$. So $i_k$ could represent different people and $s_k$ could be their height for example. My task is to have an unbiased estimate of the population mean $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n s_i$$ from a random sample from the dataset of size $n$.

To generate an estimation sample, we are given that each data point $i_k$ also has an **unknown** probability of membership $0 < p < 1$ which denotes its probability of membership in the sample, i.e. to generate a sample $S$, we start with an empty set and for $k = 1 \cdots N$, item $i_k$ is added to $S$ with probability $p$ and rejected otherwise, thus the expected sample size is $n = p \cdot N$. This is a little different from the usual scenario where $n$ is fixed by the sampler.

So let's assume we are given a sample $S_0$ of size $n_0$ generated by the above process (unknown membership probability). Then the Horvitz-Thompson estimator is given by $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{n_0}{\frac{s_i}{p}},$$ but $p$ is not known in this case, so I can't use it (I guess I could substitute the MLE for $p$ which should be $\frac{n_0}{N}$ but it's not the same)

If on the other hand I take the generative process that produced $S_0$ to be "Fix $n_0$, then sample $n_0$ points randomly from the dataset", then am I allowed to say "well the probability of any item being in $S_0$ is $\frac{n_0}{N}$ so let me use Horvitz-Thompson with $p = \frac{n_0}{N}$ which gives me
$$E\left[\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{n_0}{\frac{s_i}{p}}\right] = E\left[\frac{N}{n_0}\cdot\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{n_0} s_i \right]$$
which reduces to the expectation of the sample mean.

I'm rather uncomfortable with it though, since the observed sample is exactly the same and the only thing that's changed is my prior knowledge (or guess) of the process. But in this case, both methods of generating $S_0$ should produce the same distribution **conditioned on $n_0$** (i.e. over subsets of the dataset of size $n_0$), right?

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could comment on the (in)validity of my thought process... Thanks!